# CocoaPodsでCould not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'と'FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage-Swift.h' file not foundのビルドエラーが出ます

Tags: firebase, cocoapods

インテルベースのMacBook Pro、Xcode 15.2で、以下のPodfileを使って生成したプロジェクトが、
`Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'`と`'FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage-Swift.h' file not found`のビルドエラーでビルドが通りません。
Excluded architecturesの設定でarm64を除外していますし、
毎回Derrivedデータのキャッシュを削除してクリーンビルドしても解決しません。
1ヶ月以上悩んでいるので、どなたかご教授お願いできませんでしょうか。

以下使用Podfile

```rb
 $ios_version = '12'
 
 platform :ios, $ios_version
 
 $firebase_version = '10.19.0'
 
 # firebase関係
 def firebase_core_pods
   # pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
   pod 'Firebase/Core', $firebase_version
   pod 'Firebase/Auth', $firebase_version
   pod 'Firebase/Database', $firebase_version
   pod 'Firebase/Performance', $firebase_version
   pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', $firebase_version
   pod 'Firebase/Storage', $firebase_version
   pod 'Firebase/Messaging', $firebase_version
 end
 
 target 'MyApp' do
   # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic > frameworks
 
   # Pods for MyApp
   use_modular_headers!
   pod 'GRDB.swift'
   pod 'SVProgressHUD'
   pod 'SDWebImage'
 
   pod 'GoogleMaps'
   pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
 
   pod 'GoogleSignIn'
   pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
   pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
   pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
   
   firebase_core_pods
   
   pod 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop', $firebase_version
   pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
   pod 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics'
   pod 'FirebaseSharedSwift'
   
   pod 'PromisesSwift'
   pod 'RecaptchaInterop'
   pod 'RxSwift'
   pod 'RxCocoa'
   pod 'RxWebKit', :git => 'https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxWebKit.git'
   pod 'RxDataSources'
   pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
   pod 'ObjectMapper'
 
   pod 'Toast-Swift'
 
   # page control
   pod 'CHIPageControl'
 
 
   target 'MyAppTests' do
     inherit! :search_paths
     # Pods for testing
     # pod 'Firebase', '>= 10.19.0'
   end
 
   target 'MyAppUITests' do
     inherit! :search_paths
     # Pods for testing
     # pod 'Firebase', '>= 10.19.0'
   end 
 end
 
 
 # インストール後に実行される
 post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
      end
    end
   installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
      project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = $ios_version
       end
      end
   end
 end
```

##### 補足情報

File not foundが表示されている該当箇所を調べると
`Pods/FIrebase/CoreOnly/FIrebase.h`
で Xcode上から参照先を辿ると内部のヘッダーファイルが全て?で存在しませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OhterLinkerFlagsから不要なライブラリの参照を削除する事で自己解決出来ました。

Answer (score 0):

> 'FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage-Swift.h' file not found

無駄に悩むより、エラーメッセージを読んで理解しよう。
ファイルがない、とおっしゃってます。
まずはこのファイルがどこに有るか探してみては。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。@y_waiwaiさん 
File not foundは理解していますが該当箇所が```Pods/FIrebase/CoreOnly/FIrebase.h```で
Xcode上から参照先を辿ると内部のヘッダーファイルが全て?で存在しないのですがライブラリ内なのでこちらからは対応できないんですよね。

Comment: あくまでそのファイルが存在しないというメッセージです。ライブラリがどーとかは全く関係ないです。で、そのファイルはどこにあるんでしょうか

Comment: 存在しないという事は分かっています。問題のファイルはプロジェクト内にありません。このコードはcocoapodsから入れたのでFirebaseStorage-Swift.hがないのは依存関係が問題だと思うのでこれを解決したいです。